# Mock JPA/Hibernate database

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, jpa

Certain features of some ORM technologies (JPA EntityManager's, Hibernate Session's, etc...) can act as an "object-cache" around standard JDBC connections.

For some *testing* purposes, if I don't actually need to persist any data (never commit anything to the database, either a physical or embedded/in-memory one) and the just the ORM's object-level cache is completely sufficient, is there any way I just can completely eliminate (or mock out) the need for a database at all?

**To clarify: no embedded or in-memory databases. I really mean no databases at all (or at most, a datasource/connection mock that does absolutely nothing).

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is use JPA and configure it to use HSQL in a memory only mode. You get the full JPA feature set with nothing being written to disk.

Comment: I know I can use embedded/in-memory databases, but that's not the point; I'm trying to *completely* eliminate (or mock out) the need for a database at all. I *only* need the entityManager's or session's object-level cache -- not even any database *at all* (even an in-memory one!). So, back to my question, is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

A late followup, but for anyone coming across this post, [Acolyte](http://cchantep.github.io/acolyte/) provides a mocking JDBC driver that I think is what the OP was seeking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mock framework like [dirty-mockito](http://code.google.com/p/dirty-mockito/wiki/JpaSupport). For example

```
@Mock
private EntityManager em;

@Mock
private Query query;

private WidgetDao widgetDao;

@Test
public void testFindByName() {
  Widget widget = new Widget();

  when(em.createNamedQuery("WidgetDao.findByName")).thenReturn(query);
  when(query.getResultList()).thenReturn(Collections.singletonList(widget));

  assertSame(widget, widgetDao.findByName("Bob"));

  verify(query).setParameter("name", "Bob");
}
```

Comment: I'm not trying to mock out the EntityManager --- that object is supposed to be the *real* instance! I'm trying to mock out the underlying *DataSource* instead -- not using any database (physical or embedded/in-memory) at all.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to test? You're saying that for "For some testing purposes [..] just the ORM's object-level cache is completely sufficient". What do you actually mean?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with an embedded data source. When the `EntityManager` is created the provider (i.e. Hibernate) injects the `DataSource` according to what's been defined in the persistence unit. You can mock the `DataSource` is you use `JdbcTemplate` as explained here http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?85437-Mocking-SimpleJdbcTemplate

Comment: Just that there's no need for it. If I never (ever!) need to commit any data, why do I need a **real** *database* (either physical or embedded/in-memory)? The ORM object-cache is completely sufficient for my purposes here; having a real database that one never commits anything to nothing more than just unnecessary testing baggage. It *doesn't matter* if it's physical or embedded/in-memory.